# d3 js onclicknode function only returning the id element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

im using d3 js graph with the given data as graph input,

when i click a node  the  onclickNode function is invoked , and there iam trying to get the '**cusid**' from the graph data. but '**id**' is the only element that i got from the onclicknode function. can anyone help me to get the **cusid** by this onclickNode event ? Thanks in advance.

```
data =
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "Root",
            "size": 1000,
            "fontSize": 18,
            "fontColor": "white",         
        },
        {
            "id": "name1",
            "size": 500,
            "fontSize": 18,
            "color": "blue",
            "cusid": "105084"
        },
        {
            "id": "name2",
            "size": 500,
            "fontSize": 18,
            "color": "blue",
            "cusid": "193854"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "source": "Root",
            "target": "name1"
        },
        {
            "source": "Root",
            "target": "name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

my graph code is

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";



class  D3 extends Component {
 

  onClickNode =(id)=> {
    console.log("Graph id ",id);
    if(id !=='Root'){
       this.props.history.push(`/player/${id}`)
    }
  };

render(){
  
  if(this.props.data !==undefined){
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <Graph
            id="graph-id" // id is mandatory, if no id is defined rd3g will throw an error
            data={this.props.data}
            config={this.props.config}
            onClickNode={this.onClickNode}
            
          />;
        </div>
      );
  }
  
  }

}


export default withRouter(D3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we have access to `data`, then using [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find), search the nodes by ID to get the right node, then get its property, here `cusid`.

```
const onClickNode = id => {
  const node = data.nodes.find(d => d.id === id)
  const cusid = node.cusid
}
```

Comment: what if there is more than one ' id'  having same names in the json ?  i will get matched with multiple 'cusid'  when performing the array.find () method. is there any different way that i can i access the 'cusid' on node click event  like passing the 'id' and 'cusid' at the same time ?

Comment: In that case, why not set `cusid` as `id` in your data?

Comment: i have done that.  but i need to display names instead of numbers .